# Clear contents of outer div and add different number of inner divs

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the number of inner divs from 2 to 3 but the javascript code isn't letting me. I want to get all the inner divs from the entire page and then add every three to the next inner div:

```js
var innerElems = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
var outerElems = document.getElementsByClassName("outer");

// Remove contents of outer divs
for (let i = 0; i < outerElems.length; i++) {
  outerElems[i].innerHTML = "";
}

let x = 0;

for (let j = 0; j < innerElems.length; j++) {
  outerElems[j].innerHTML = innerElems[x];
  x++;
  outerElems[j].innerHTML = innerElems[x];
  x++;
  outerElems[j].innerHTML = innerElems[x];
  x++
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" id="outer1ID">
  <div class="inner">
      <div class="anotherDiv">
          Contents A
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
      <div class="anotherDiv">
          Contents B
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer" id="outer2ID">
  <div class="inner">
      <div class="anotherDiv">
          Contents C
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
      <div class="anotherDiv">
          Contents D
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer" id="outer3ID">
  <div class="inner">
      <div class="anotherDiv">
          Contents E
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
      <div class="anotherDiv">
          Contents F
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the final result to look like:

```
<div class="outer" id="outer1ID">
      <div class="inner">
          <div class="anotherDiv">
              Contents A
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="inner">
          <div class="anotherDiv">
              Contents B
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="inner">
          <div class="anotherDiv">
              Contents C
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="outer" id="outer2ID">
      <div class="inner">
          <div class="anotherDiv">
              Contents D
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="inner">
          <div class="anotherDiv">
              Contents E
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="inner">
          <div class="anotherDiv">
              Contents F
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

When running the script, the HTML just shows "object HTMLelement" when adding to the outer divs

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your inner divs will have the same content, you can use this approach to avoid unecessary changes in the DOM:

```js
const $outer = document.getElementsByClassName('outer');
const $inner = document.querySelector('.inner');

function addInnerElement() {
    for (const $el of $outer) {
        $el.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', $inner.cloneNode(true));
    }
}

addInnerElement();
```

Comment: My inner divs have different contents but the element attributes remain the same

Comment: @Rob So you want a inner div without any content, but with the same attributes?

Comment: I've updated my post to show what I mean. Apologies if I was unclear

Answer (score 0):

After removing the content of your outer element, you can create a loop that will iterate **3 times** (you want 3 inner divs). In this loop, you can create a new `div` element with `document.createElement('div')`.

You can now add the class `inner` with `classList.add('inner')`.

After that, you can append the new `inner div` to the `outer div` with `.appendChild(element);`.

In the example below, I have added a little bit of CSS to differentiate the `outer div`(Purple) from the `inner div`(Cyan).

Here is an example of what you can do:

```js
var outerElems = document.getElementsByClassName("outer");


// Remove contents of outer divs
for(let j = 0; j < outerElems.length; j++)
{
outerElems[j].innerHTML = "";
for(let i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
  var innerElems = document.createElement('div');
  innerElems.style.background = "cyan";
  innerElems.style.margin = "5px";
  innerElems.innerText = "Inner Div " + i;
  innerElems.classList.add('inner');
  outerElems[j].appendChild(innerElems);;
}
}
```

```css
.outer{
background-color: purple;
height: 100px;
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
}

.inner{
background-color: cyan;
height: 20px;
margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" id="outer1ID">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="outer" id="outer2ID">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="outer" id="outer3ID">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have updated my post to show what I am trying to achieve. Each of the inners have different contents but I want this content to carry over when changing the number of inners in the outer

Answer (score 0):

run code snippet to see that my solution works

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
 .inner {
   background-color: red;
   margin: 0.5rem;
 }
 .outer {
   background-color: blue
 }
</style>
<body>
<div class="outer" id="outer1ID">
   outer
    <div class="inner">
    inner
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
    inner
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="outer" id="outer2ID">
   outer
    <div class="inner">
    inner
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
    inner
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="outer" id="outer3ID">
   outer
    <div class="inner">
    inner
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
    inner
    </div>
  </div>
<script>
var innerElems = document.getElementsByClassName("inner")
var outerElems = document.getElementsByClassName("outer")
var lastElement = outerElems[2]

for (let [i, el] of [...outerElems].entries()) { // loop over all the remaining outer elements
  i !== 2 && el.append(lastElement.children[i].cloneNode(true)) // add inner elements from last outer element
}

// remove last one
lastElement.remove()

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have updated my post to show what I am trying to achieve. Each of the inners have different contents but I want this content to carry over when changing the number of inners in the outer

Comment: I modified my solution so that inner divs from last outer div are now being moved into fist and second outer div, without modifying them.